# Google Translation case insensitive

Tags: google-translate

I am using Google Translations api v2 and I see the issue is not maintains the case sensitive. Eg: "Evaluate Network" (English) word is translated to "evaluar la Red" (Spanish) but I expected the translation word is "Evaluar le Red". How can I maintain the case sensitive Google Translations? Thanks.

Comment: Capitalization Rules are different in different Languages. For example, in German every Noun is written with an upper-case initial Letter. Would you really want Google Translate to reproduce this Convention when translating Text from German into English? In English, Titles of Books are written with upper-case Initials on every Word; but in French this would be incorrect. For best Results, the Output of Google Translate is supposed to be further edited by a Human.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, the only workaround I found was:

```
font {text-transform: capitalize}
```

in your main css file and it gets the job DONE.